# http server with basic autentification in qt

Tags: qt, http, https

I'm writing application which should have build in simple http server for remote control access. I'm using Qt and want to provide to user a way to autentificate.
I've found an [http server realisation(by Stefan Frings).](http://stefanfrings.de/qtwebapp/index-en.html) Can some one help with solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. It is rather easy by the way....
We just need to add  `WWW-Authenticate` into header and on server side check creditinals.